# batchget with 1 request in throwing "Quota exceeded for quota group 'AnalyticsDefaultGroup' and limit 'CLIENT_PROJECT-1d"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Hi this was working for me a couple of weeks ago, however i keep getting this now.

Quota exceeded for quota group 'AnalyticsDefaultGroup' and limit 'CLIENT_PROJECT-1d'

error 429

As far as i am aware this should reset midnight pacific time. But it does not seem to have done that.

Even on the test account I get this error, I know I have resolved the issue that was causing it but I don't know why I still get this error.

Has it blacklisted the viewid? or IP? How can I get more info so I can resolve this issue.